# distance between solutions in a convex optimization

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, dual-cone

Assume that you have the following convex optimization problem:

$\min_{M} \|b+A\ M\ v\|_2$

subject to :

$\|M\|_{2}<1$ (maximum singular value less than 1)

where M is a suare matrix (n by n), A is a tall matrix (m by n) where $m>n^2$ and b and v are vectors.

Now assume that you find the optimum matrix M (M is square) for two sets of given vectors b and v and matrix A. In other words, $M^{const.}_1$ solves the problem for given $b_1$,$v_1$ and $A_1$.

Similarly you find another solution for the second set of given parameters:   $M^{const.}_2$ solves the problem for given $b_2$,$v_2$ and $A_2$.

Now consider the unconstrained problem which is nothing but:

$\min_{M} \|b+A\ M\ v\|_2$

again you find another two matrices namely $M^{unconst.}_1$ and $M^{unconst.}_2$ which solves the unconstrained problem for the two sets of {$b_1$,$v_1$ and $A_1$}, and {$b_2$,$v_2$ and $A_2$.} respectively.

The question here is, can we say something like this?

$\|M^{const.}_2-M^{const.}_1\|<\|M^{unconst.}_2-M^{unconst.}_1\|$

In other words, the distance of the solutions in constrained problem is smaller than the distance of the two in unconstrained problem.

Comment: I tried to prove for the case where we have vectors instead of matrix optimization. in that case if it is a 2 norm and symmetric (contours are circles and not ellipse) then this inequality seems to be valid. But here is more complicated since we are dealing with matrices.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\min_M \|b+AMv\|_2$ is equivalent to $\min_m \|b+(v^\top \otimes A)m\|_2$ where $m=\mathrm{vec}(M)$, and $\|M\|_\infty=\|m\|_\infty$ ? So you could restrict your analysis to vectors.

Comment: $\|M\|_\infty$ is *not* the maximum singular value. That's $\|M\|_2$. Please edit, so people don't waste their time like they did with your previous question.

Comment: @davcha by infinity norm I meant maximum singular value, which is apperantly a wrong notation so I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach? 
I use @davcha 's idea to convert the matrix to vector m. 
so we have the following unconstrained optimization problem:

$\min_{m} \|b+V\ m\|_2$
where V denotes  $(v^{T}*A)$.

Now by decomposing matrix $V=\tilde{V}\ T$, where $\tilde{V}^{T}\tilde{V}=I$, leads to

$\min_{m} \|b+\tilde{V}\ \tilde{m}\|_2$

where $\tilde{m}=T\ m$.

So now by this transformation, the cost function contours are spherically symmetric (they are circles rather than ellipse). Thus, here the following inequality should be valid:

$\|\tilde{m}^{const.}_2-\tilde{m}^{const.}_1\|<\|\tilde{m}^{unconst.}_2-\tilde{m}^{unconst.}_1\|$.

am I right?

Comment: Is there always such a decomposition ?

Comment: svd decomposition. but i think i made a mistake here because coordinates will change going from $A_1$,$b_1$ and $v_1$ to the second one.

Comment: It's not clear how you're constraining the maximum singular value of $M$ here. Remember, $\|M\|_2$ is not the same as $\|\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(M)\|_2$. On the other hand, $\|M\|_F=(\sum_i\sigma_i^2(M))^{1/2}\equiv\|\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(M)\|_2$.

Comment: Yes, I think my approach is totally wrong since as I said the contours are not the same when going from $A_1$ to $A_2$. Basically, this problem is still open.